# 'Next' keyword misunderstood in specific Ruby code

Tags: ruby, iteration

I did a small programme to count words in the array:

```
array = ["first line",
     "second   line",
     "",
     "  fourth line   containing  a few  more words   ",
     "fifth line "]

words = 0

array.each do |s|
  wis = 0
  s.length.times do |i|
    if i == 0
      if s[i] != " "
        wis = 1
        next #HERE IT COMES.
      end
    end
    if s[i] != " " and s[i-1] == " "
      wis += 1
    end

  end
  words += wis
end

puts "Words in the array: #{words}"
```

OUTPUT:

```
Words in the array: 13
```

It works properly, but there's a one thing which I can't understand. I know that `next` keyword leaves the current iteration but I don't know how it exactly works right here. If I omit it from the code, Output would be `Words in the array: 14`. I know `next` can be replaced with `else` condition and that's the problem - I don't know how to define it.

- Can you please explain me how does `next` work in the code?
- Can you give me the alternative solution for that `if` condition without using `next` keyword?

Thank you

Comment: Not answering the question, but just to show a more Ruby way `array.join(' ').split(' ').count #=> 13`

Comment: Your code is very un-Ruby-like. I suggest you consider posting it at SO's sister-site, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby). There you will get useful suggestions for improving it.

Comment: I know, I started studying IT last month so I don't know many methods in Ruby yet. Thank you for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, there are a lot of more elegant ways of writing a word count in Ruby. However, I'll try and answer your specific questions as there's still something to learn here.

As you've mentioned `next` leaves the current iteration. In your example it means that when both the `i == 0` condition and the `s[i] != " "` condition are true then the `next` will execute and the `if s[i] != " " and s[i-1] == " "...` part will be skipped for that iteration.

The reason for getting a count of 14 words when you remove the `next` relies on knowing what happens when a negative index is used for a string. In this line:

```
if s[i] != " " and s[i-1] == " "
```

when `i` is 0 this is equivalent to

```
s[0] != " " and s[-1] == " "
```

`s[-1]` means the *last character* of the string. This is true for the line `"fifth line "` so the result is that the first word of that line is counted twice.

To replace the `next` with an `else` condition you'd need to arrange an alternative way for the `if s[i] != " " and s[i-1] == " "...` not to execute if `i == 0 and s[i] != " "` so something like:

```
if i == 0 and s[i] != " "
  wis = 1
elsif s[i] != " " and s[i-1] == " "
  wis += 1
end
```

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to the use of `next`, I suggest you to read [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278285/next-versus-if-in-a-each-loop).

About your code, I could tell you that learning Ruby requires a greater change in your way of programming. It is not just a matter of using Ruby syntax, but also of exploring Ruby potential to make things simple.

For instance, you could do your taks without any `if` at all.

```
array = ["first line",
     "second   line",
     "",
     "  fourth line   containing  a few  more words   ",
     "fifth line "]

count = array.inject(0) { |c, item| c + item.strip.split(" ").count }

puts count
```

This would give you

```
13
```

which is exactly the number of words, and with no `if` at all.

And this is not even close to be the best way. I'm sure this could be done even shorter.

Comment: Using `array.each` with an accumulator defined as a local variable before loop is php-style, it has nothing to do with ruby style and is in fact a code smell in ruby world. In ruby we do use `each_with_object` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember that!

Comment: Since your answer is written in a teaching tone, you might consider changing `each` to `each_with_object` right there.

Comment: I'll do that. By the way, I don't pretend to be a Ruby teacher. I was just telling the OP exactly what I was told. I am an apprentice yet.

Comment: May be I sounded like a teacher because I am a Math teacher. :)

Comment: Here it is, @mudasobwa. I think using `inject` is better than `each_with_object` in this case. Ant thanks for telling me about this code smell. I learned a bit more Ruby now, studying to make to make this answer better.

Comment: Indeed, `inject` is definitely better here. Thanks for making changes, this effort makes SO better.

Comment: My pleasure. I am learning lot here and it is great to contribute, even in a small point.

Answer (score 3):

simple example using "next" keyword

```
(1..10).each do |a|
   next if a.even?
   puts a
end
```

output:-

```
1
3   
5
7
9
```

**Usage of next in a block:** When next is used within a block, it causes the block to exit immediately, returning control to the iterator method, which may then begin a new iteration by invoking the block again

Answer (score 1):

Next jumps back to the beginning of the codeblock, and in this case to the next array element.

The shortest possible answer how to do this better is IMHO this

```
puts "Words in the array: #{array.join(' ').split(/\W+/).length}"
# Words in the array: 13
```

Some explanation:
While working with strings it is often best to use regular expressions, to make it easy I start with combining all array elements to one string with: `array.join(' ')`
The space is used as a separator to prevent that words are joined together.
This string is split again with the regular expression between the //'s, namely \W+ which means a series of non delimiter characters (thus a word).
This array is taken the length of and so giving the number of words in the string/array.

EDIT: it's two chars shorter using scan instead of split and count instead of length 8:)

```
array.join(' ').scan(/\W+/).count
```

Comment: When using `scan` would `\w+` be better than `\W+`?

Comment: Please be aware that `\w` matches e.g. “1_”. When one wants to match letters, one should explicitly match letters with `\p{L}`.